# iTextSharp GetTextFromPage Only Returns First Page

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp Version 5.5.12

The code knows there are 10 pages in my pdf. In my loop, only the first page is returned.

```
    PdfReader Pdf = new PdfReader(PATH_TO_PDF);

    for (intPageNum = 1; intPageNum <= Pdf.NumberOfPages; intPageNum++)
    {

        ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
        string strPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(Pdf, intPageNum, strategy);

    }
```

As I step through all ten iterations of the loop, only on the first iteration does strPageText have any text in it.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I used the exact same code and it works for me, maybe your pdf file is corrupted or something. Have you tried with a different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" appears to be a scanning software setting that combines multiple pdf files into one document (file).

Image Capture Plus software has a Job Setting, on the File tab, under OCR Settings for Searchable PDF. Make sure it is set to "All Pages".